# How to fix the EKF pose when the robot is definitely not moving?

Tags: navigation, ekf, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a robot with

- cameras providing absolute **poses** and
- wheel encoders providing **odometry** (i.e. x, y and yaw velocities).

A **robot_localization_ekf** node fuses both measurements and yields good results.

However, I'm struggling with the following situation: The robot is standing still (the wheel encoders yield very certain zero velocities) and the cameras don't yield any poses (there are no visual markers in the current field of view). **How can we prevent the EKF from predicting a filtered odometry with huge uncertainties, when we know the robot is not moving?** I thought about

- pausing the entire EKF node or
- dynamically decreasing the process noise

until I either receive camera poses or non-zero velocities. But, I guess, both is impossible with the current version of robot_localization.

Sure, since there is no absolute information for a period of time, the EKF pose uncertainty grows unboundedly. But there should be a possibility to circumvent this behavior in certain situations. Although the absolute pose is unknown at the moment, it doesn't change for sure and it's uncertainty doesn't change as well.

Do you have any ideas how to handle this case?

(By the way, I know of other applications, e.g. with advanced driver assistance systems, where they adjust the process noise depending on the situation: driving straight, turning at an intersection, preventing a collision, ...)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227775/how-to-fix-the-ekf-pose-when-the-robot-is-definitely-not-moving?/) by [Falko](https://answers.ros.org/users/23523/falko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 268 on 2016-02-29

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're correct, there is no way to handle this situation currently. The process noise covariance matrix is currently assumed to be static, but there are clearly situations where this isn't ideal. This should really be handled by monitoring the velocity  and freezing the error growth when the robot stops moving. There are forks that already do this, and I will look into merging those changes upstream. Feel free to file a ticket on the r_l GitHub page.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Falko](https://answers.ros.org/users/23523/falko/) on 2016-03-01**:
Thanks Tom, that would be great! :)

**Comment by [Falko](https://answers.ros.org/users/23523/falko/) on 2016-03-01**:
Just for cross-referring the github ticket: https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/issues/260

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not worked with this package but here are some guesses:

- Make a pose "sensor" [edit: I previously said odometery instead of pose] which sends measurements of zero velocity with zero* variance. It only sends out such messages when the odometry message has had zero velocty for a short time. When the robot starts moving again there will be a short delay before the EKF acknowledges movement based on the sensor_timeout value.
- Use the [manual state reset](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization#Manual_State_Reset) to continually put the system back to its values before forward prediction

*Dont literally use 0, or it will be set to 1e-6 (see the last note on [the sensor data page](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/Preparing%20Your%20Sensor%20Data))

---

Originally posted by [vaziri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26088/vaziri/) with karma: 46 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Falko](https://answers.ros.org/users/23523/falko/) on 2016-03-01**:
Thanks @vaziri, but the sensor is already sending zero velocities. This doesn't prevent the *pose* uncertainty to grow due to the process noise. The state reset might work, but I guess it would destroy the current variance information by nailing it to a fixed pose.

**Comment by [vaziri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26088/vaziri/) on 2016-03-01**:
The manual state reset includes the covariance matrix; I think you might not have to destroy anything.

**Comment by [Falko](https://answers.ros.org/users/23523/falko/) on 2016-03-01**:
Yes, you're right: The set_pose topic is of type PoseWithCovarianceStamped. So this would probably suffice as a workaround.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2016-03-01**:
I'm not sure what set_state might do to the covariance of the rest of the filter state (velocities, accelerations, cross-covariances). Try a virtual pose sensor and send pose measurements with small covariance when the odometry is 0, as suggested in the (updated) answer above.